# laravel subfolders .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5

I have a question (and really tried already a lot of things).

this is the folder structure on my root:

```
.htaccess (root)
/2014 
/2015 
/2016 
/2017
    .htaccess (2017->laravel redirect)
    public
        index.php
        css
```

where 2017 has a Laravel website.

I know I need an .htaccess file inside the 2017 folder to rewrite to the public folder where the index.php file is /public
This is the .htaccess file in the 2017 folder to achieve this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

First problem I have here is that now inside my Laravel code, when I access the website via www.dotfmp.com/2017 the $REQUEST_URI contains now "2017/{page}" instead of only "{page}".

My second question is what should be my .htaccess file in the root, so that any request coming on the www.dotfmp.com website will go to /2017 folder, however www.dotfmp.com/{folder} should go to the intended folder.

An answer would be nice, an explanation even better, and a good resource the best :)

Thanks in advance

Andries

Comment: Isn't that the expected result? You URL should now be `http://example.com/page` (without 2017). If you add 2017 it'll become part of the page.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but no :) The .htaccess file is in 2017 just to rewrite the / to the /public folder of laravel. So that only should serve so that www.dotfmp.com/2017 would rewrite to www.dotfmp.com/2017/public/index.php. I updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: solved, I just removed the .htaccess from the 2017 folder to the root and changed the folder from public to 2017/public